# How can I check if any details of a task in any project are modified?

Tags: api, asana

I've fetched some tasks for "Project A" and suppose the 'task notes' or 'assignee' of the task is changed. How can I check in my next request if there are any changes?

Will I have to get all the tasks and check for their "modified_at" and compare it with some local value? or there's an easy way? (because if I do this, I'll have to get all the tasks and then send request for each task to get it's modified_at, so If I've 100 tasks for a project, I'll need 100 requests?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm dealing with the same issue. There isn't a great way to handle getting tasks that have been modified since a particular timestamp, but Asana's api says that filtering options will exist in the future.

But there is a better solution:

```
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT_ID/tasks?opt_fields=modified_at
```

This will give you all the tasks for that project with their modified_at timestamps. You'll still have to request the individual tasks that have changed. The fields list can be a comma delineated list.